# Passing nested parameters for instance variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**strong text**I'm trying to make dynamic select boxes via ["data-remote attribute for select boxes"](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#1375-Using-an-unobtrusive-Ajax-UJS-onchange-call-to-the-controller-action). In console it seems that i'm getting right parameters(the id of selected make), but I can't figure it out how to pass it to controller to get models with matching make_id:s.

**Heres the attached_vehicles form part from _form.html.erb**

```
<div class="vehicle_field">
    <%= f.fields_for :attached_vehicles do |av| %>
    <p>Select make</p>
    <%= av.select :make, (@makes.collect { |m| [m.make_name, m.id] }), { include_blank: "Select make" }, { data: { remote: true, url: "update_make_models", name: "make", update: "#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_model"} } %><br>
    <p>Select model</p>
    <%= av.collection_select :model, @models, (render "make_models/make_model"), { prompt: "Select model" } %><br>
    ...
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**../views/diys/update_make_models.coffee**

```
$.empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render "make_models/make_model") %>")
```

**../diys_controller.rb**

```
...
def update_make_models
  @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", params[:make])
end

def new
  @diy = Diy.new
  @step = @diy.steps.new
  @attached_vehicle = @diy.attached_vehicles.new
  @step.add_images_to_steps.new
  @makes = Make.all
  @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", params[:make_id])
end
...
```

**../views/make_models/_make_model.html.erb**

```
<% @models.collect do |models| %>
   <option value="<%= models.id %>"><%= models.make_model_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

**And here's what i'm getting in console after selecting make in makes select box**

```
Started GET "/diys/update_make_models?diy%5Battached_vehicles_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmake%5D=12" for ::1 at 2016-02-18 20:22:35 +0200 Processing by DiysController#update_make_models as JS
  Parameters: {"diy"=>{"attached_vehicles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"make"=>"12"}}}}
  MakeModel Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "make_models".* FROM "make_models" WHERE (make_id = NULL)
  Rendered make_models/_make_model.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered diys/update_make_models.coffee (491.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 628ms (Views: 626.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**Edit**

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `attached_vehicles_attributes' for #<DiysController:0x5757648>):
  app/controllers/diys_controller.rb:28:in `update_make_models'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params` hash is(according to logs): `{"diy"=>{"attached_vehicles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"make"=>"12"}}}}`. So, if you want to get `:make_id` from it, you should write:

```
def update_make_models
  @models = MakeModel.where(make_id: params["diy"]["attached_vehicles_attributes"]["0"]["make"])
end
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error in console after selecting make `NameError (undefined local variable or method `attached_vehicles_attributes' for #<DiysController:0x5757648>):
  app/controllers/diys_controller.rb:28:in `update_make_models'`